# Deezer API radio stream vs Apple audio streaming limitation

Tags: ios, iphone, deezer

I have an app that streams a radio on Deezer thanks to the deezer api (iOS SDK) but with cellular network it seems to go over 5Mb/5minutes :S

The Apple guidelines are kind of clear about it:

*Audio streaming content over a cellular network may not use more than 5MB over 5 minutes
(https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html point 9.3)

So... my question is, do you have any idea if the Deezer api allows to grab a lower bitrate stream?

I haven't found anything letting hope we can. The only solution I see is warning the user he/she has to turn on wifi to access audio but it'd be kind of frustrating.

Comment: By the way, using Charles, I can see several times the mpeg stream (often 6, depending on the track) and it seems there's no difference between each stream...

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to grab a lower bitrate tracks.

As for the several requests you see in charles for the same track, it is because the SDK ask for chuncks (see the Range: header in the requests).